# SSO with a 3rd party using Azure AD

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

I have an organization wanting to do SSO using SAML 2.0 against my node.js based web app. When clicking a link for x.myapp.com, I want to utilize their IdP (which uses Azure AD with SAML 2.0) and redirect to my app and provide a few attributes to me.

I found passport-azure-ad and saml2-js npm packages but I don't see any examples that cover this scenario. Has anyone done this seemingly simple use case and provide any links or examples? I only found iOS or Android examples thus far but not web-based node.js apps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding , you are looking for a Azure AD SAML login nodejs demo. 
[This demo](https://github.com/ritstudentgovernment/passport-saml-example) will be helpful for you and it works for me.

If you want to use Azure AD as your idp, you should do some modify as below :

1.Create a folder named "cert" . Run this command to create key.pem and cert.pem under cert folder:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

2. Go to Azure AD ,download idp cert here ,rename it as "cert_idp.pem" directly and place it under cert folder too :
   [image]
   [image]
   3.Creatring a file named ".env" with content below :

```html
CALLBACK_URL=https://<your host>/login/callback
ENTRY_POINT=<find the value in the capture below>
ISSUER=<your Azure AD APP ID>
SESSION_SECRET=secret
```

[image]

With the steps done , you can run this demo . in my case, I expose 4006 port to public network using ngrok , once you access the app , you will be redirected to Azure AD SAML login page to login:
[image]

Modify the get method under "/" as below to get MSAL token info after you logged in successfully:

```
app.get('/',
  ensureAuthenticated, 
  function(req, res) {
    res.send('Authenticated, SAML token info :'  + JSON.stringify(req.session.passport.user));
  }
);
```

If there is anything unclear , pls feel free to let me know : )

Comment: What are the purpose of these certs?